# Load json file in Typescript as an object instead of a module

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

I have the following import in a code I am using:

```
import * as schema from "../schema.json";
```

Right now, the schema variable is a module and if I want to access my JSON object, I need to do schema.default.
If I change `import * as schema` to `import schema`, then the schema variable is the JSON content (an object).

I was wondering if it was possible using webpack or any babel plugin to load an object with `import * as schema` ?

Current babel config file:

```
  presets: ['@babel/preset-typescript', '@babel/preset-react', ['@babel/preset-env', { modules: 'commonjs' }]],
  plugins: [
    'babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring',
    ['@babel/plugin-transform-for-of', { loose: true }],
    '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
      // ["@babel/plugin-transform-typescript", {allowNamespaces: true}],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
    ['styled-components', { ssr: true }]
  ]
```

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a **typings.d.ts** in /src/ folder with following code:

```
}
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any
  export default value
}
```

And in my component:

```
import data from "./data.json"

export default function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(elem => (
        <h1> {elem.title}</h1> 
        <p> {elem.body}</p>
      )}
     </div>
)}
```

Re-run the server and it worked

Comment: The thing is that I am using a lot of codes that I "can't" modify and you're importing with `import data from "./data.json"`. What I want is the same with `import * as data from "./data.json"`.